# How to claim VAT refund travelling from Amsterdam to London by train

Tags: netherlands, amsterdam, tax-refunds, vat

After brexit, travellers from EU to UK can reclaim vat on purchases. My question is how can this be done from Amsterdam?

Is there a customs office near the Eurostar entrance so that the VAT refund forms can be stamped?

Comment: I can’t find any trace of a customs office in Amsterdam Centraal. You may need to hop to Schipol to have your forms stamped. You should try to call them to ask for more info, you’ll find contact details [here](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/standaard_functies/individuals/contact/calling/dutch-customs-telephone-numbers-for-private-clients) and [here](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/luggage/from_a_non_eu_country/contact-customs-offices). Let us know what they say!

Comment: @jcaron I am not sure they’d let you do it at Schiphol. I found this info - https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/guide-vat-refund-visitors-eu_en . You’d have the same problem traveling from say some random stop in France to Zurich on a non-stop train. While there is an office in Garrett du Nord, it seems not to be the case for Amsterdam Centraal, which doesn’t run many service to London.

Comment: They definitely don't make it easy to avoid paying the fee to the handlers at the airport.  You can get the full refund if you do it by mail, but that requires going somewhere to prove you removed the item from EU and then receiving a check in euro when you're no longer in country.  :-(

Comment: @WGroleau I don’t know what you mean by doing it by Mail. The important thing is getting a custom stamp. It is not clear if Amsterdam Centraal has an officer who can do the stamping.

Comment: [According to Eurostar](https://www.eurostar.com/us-en/brexit), "when travelling from the Netherlands to the UK: Arrangements for claiming VAT have not yet been finalised, the latest information from the Dutch Government can be found" [on some website that doesn't help], but it's unclear when this page was last updated.

Comment: According to the documentation I had when I was in Europe (2019 and earlier), I could send in the forms from home (and not pay the fee to the contractor that does it in an airport).  But I would have to get official proof from customs (that the items taxed had left EU) to send with it—and the refund would be a check in Euro, a nuisance to convert to anything useful when in USA.

Comment: anyone have any updates to this issue? We are traveling on the Eurostar to London from Amsterdam and need some guidance
Thanks

Comment: @user129127 it seems not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Eurostar website](https://www.eurostar.com/rw-en/travel-info/travel-planning/travel-documents/customs) has been updated. Unfortunately it does not mention any customs office in Amsterdam (emphasis mine):

> - Claiming VAT on purchases made in the EU when travelling from the EU to the UK:
>
> Non-EU residents may be able to claim back VAT on purchases made in the EU from retailers that are part of the VAT refund scheme. Please note the minimum qualifying amount may vary by country.
>
> You will need to show your purchases, receipt, passport and completed VAT refund form in your name to customs officers at the station to get your VAT refund form stamped. **The customs office can be found after passport and luggage checks in Paris Gare du Nord, Lille Europe, Marne-la-Vallée (Disneyland Paris) and Brussels-Midi/Zuid**. Please arrive at the station a little earlier than usual if you plan to claim a VAT refund.

Comment: It does not have one. At least my friend did not see one whilst travelling there. Getting off the train to do a tax refund is unrealistic.

I guess it is possible that if you go to Schiphol, they might let you do it there, but this seems like a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer by Saaru. I found this site useful to search for where customs offices are located (Step 2, search for the customs search button):
https://www.globalblue.com/shoppers/how-to-shop-tax-free/destinations/netherlands

For example I'm travelling from the Netherlands to the UK on Eurostar departing from Rotterdam. The customs offices in Rotterdam are either at the airport or the ferry terminal, none at the train station.. so I guess no VAT refund for me :(